# What is a more efficient way of classifying triangles?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have been asked (for school) to write a function that is void and outputs what type of triangle the user has entered:

```
static void typeTri()
{
    if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The triangle is equilateral.");
    }
    else if ((side1 == side2 && side2 != side3) || (side1 != side2 && side2 == side3) || (side1 == side3 && side1 != side2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The triangle is isoceles.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The triangle is scalene.");
    }
}
```

The testing seems a bit long on the 'else if'.  Any ideas?

Comment: You have three different situations, so two tests... seems reasonable to me. You don't need the *negative* tests for the isoceles version though, because we already know it's not equilateral - that's why you're in the else condition.

Comment: You have a comment by Jon Skeet himself. You sir are blessed.

Comment: Nevermind, had a brain mishap. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to logic, you can simplify your second `if`: you do not need to test for `!=`, because if they were equal, the first `if` would have been satisfied already.

```
static void typeTri()
    {
        if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The triangle is equilateral.");
        }
        else if ((side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side1 == side3))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The triangle is isoceles.");
        }
        else if ((side1 >= side2 + side3) || (side2 >= side1 + side3) || (side3 >= side1 + side2) || (side1 <= 0) || (side2 <= 0) || (side3 <= 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a Triangle");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The triangle is scalene.");
        }
    }
```

You also need to consider the case that this is not a triangle at all, but that requirement might be out of scope for this specific question.

Comment: You can also write `side1 == side2 == side3`.

Comment: No. `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'`

Comment: of course, we could add more to this solution...  make sure that side1 + side2 > side3, then do that for the other two cases, just to make sure that we really do have a triangle in the first place... but that is out of scope here.

Answer (score 4):

**Code it the way you would speak it...**

> *If all sides are equal, 'The triangle is equilateral' otherwise, if at least two sides are equal, 'The triangle is Isosceles' else, 'The triangle is scalene'.*

The `typeTri()` method written below can be spoken like the sentence above.

```
static void typeTri()
{
    if (AllSidesAreEqual(side1, side2, side3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The triangle is equilateral.");
    }
    else if (AtLeastTwoSideAreEqual(side1, side2, side3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The triangle is isoceles.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The triangle is scalene.");
    }
}

private static bool AllSidesAreEqual (int side1, int side2, int side3)
{
    return (side1 == side2) 
        && (side2 == side3);
}

private static bool AtLeastTwoSideAreEqual (int side1, int side2, int side3)
{
    return (side1 == side2)
        || (side2 == side3)
        || (side1 == side3);
}
```

Comment: This is more readable than my answer, but Tiernan was asking for efficiency.  The != is not needed in my answer, making it a little more efficient.

Comment: @Joe: OP's only concern mentioned in the question is - "The testing seems a bit long on the 'else if' ".

Answer (score 0):

This minimizes the conditionals a bit and by using the ternary operator, it's compact:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "The triangle is {0}.",
    side1 != side2
        ? (side2 != side3 && side1 != side3 ? "scalene" : "isoceles")
        : (side3 == side1 ? "equilateral" : "iscoceles");
```

Comment: And difficult to understand for beginners like him.

Comment: Fair enough. But hopefully something OP explores as he grows.

Answer (score 0):

This version reduces the conditional checks to 3 at the expense of some mathematical skulduggery:

```
int count = 0;
if (side1 - side2 != 0) count++;
if (side2 - side3 != 0) count++;
if (side3 - side1 != 0) count++;

var types = new [] { "equilateral", "invalid", "isoceles", "scalene" };

Console.WriteLine("The triangle is {0}.", types[count]);
```

The comparisons reduce comparisons of length to comparisons of differences in length for any two sides. Then a lookup into a table.

Comment: count will never equal 2, therefore types[2] should be "invalid state".  Although, I like the way you're thinking out of the box.  This looks like the method a programmer would use if he were writing in assembly code.

Comment: whoops... yes, you are correct, it can never equal 1.  I must have inverted my logic.  I was subconsciously thinking "==" instead of "!=".